# LINQ to SQL select exact matching record from many to many table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I need help with finding matching records in SQL.
My table below alleviates many to many problem, where GridToPageID is primary key, and there can be many instances of a single GridID with a different PageID.

[image]

In my application, parameter will be passed with a specific list of PageID's and I would need to query and find only records that match exact number of PageID's passed.
When I query SQL using below query it returns me all records that have 2 and more matches where I wanted to get only one record that has exactly those 2.

```
SELECT [GridID]
  FROM [AgencySalesAgreementU01].[dbo].[GridToPage]  
  where PageID in('11aida','30aida') --or any number
  group by gridid
  having COUNT (GridToPageID) = 2 --match the number of PageID's passed
```

This is the same linq-to-sql query tested in LinqPad

```
string[] allpages ={"11aida","30aida"};//,"32aida"};

var result = from gtp in GridToPage 
where allpages.Contains(gtp.PageID) 
group gtp by gtp.GridID into grp
where grp.Count() == allpages.Count() 
select grp.Key;
result.Dump();
```

The result of above query returns GridID of 261, 263 and 266 where I wanted it to return only 261.
If I pass three PageID's I would need it to return 263 and 266. 
And similarly, for only PageID '11aida' it would return 268.

Comment: In the example above, why is it not okay if 263 is returned?

Comment: I wanted to get the result for only exact match (only for two passed PageID). GridID of 263 has another record for a different PageID and I don't need to see that in results. Maybe I could filter the results afterward? @TheTTGGuy

Comment: So you want to get an ID returned that has exactly the number returned that you want, AND that number returned is the same as the number you are checking for? You will need to compare on two aggregates to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should group the numbers first and then, within the group, determine if all `PageID`s are in the `allpages` list:

```
string[] allpages ={"11aida","30aida"};//,"32aida"};
var count = allpages.Count();

var result = from gtp in GridToPage 
group gtp by gtp.GridID into grp
where grp.Count() == count 
   && grp.All(x => allpages.Contains( x.PageID))
select grp.Key;
```

Comment: works great in all places i tested! thanks so much! @gert-arnold

Comment: This will break in an Entity Framework LINQ statement.

Comment: @tdbeckett I don't think so. I answered this based on a very similar query I executed myself. Which part do you think won't translate?

Comment: .Count, .All and .Contains do not work in Entity Framework.  They work fine for lists that aren't in Entity Framework.  This is because EF translates your LINQ statement into SQL.  It doesn't know how to translate such methods.

Comment: Well, it does. But your comment made me aware of one possible improvement: it's better to do the count separately.

Answer (score 0):

This one simple change should solve your problem. Add DISTINCT to your HAVING COUNT() and change what you are counting to PageID.

EDIT: So you want to get an ID returned that has exactly the number returned that you want, AND that number returned is the same as the number you are checking for? You will need to compare on two aggregates to do that.

```
SELECT [GridID]
FROM 
    [AgencySalesAgreementU01]
    .[dbo].[GridToPage]
GROUP BY gridid
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN PageID 
                IN (
                    '11aida', 
                    '30aida'
                    ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
    = 2
    -- This checks that both were found.
    AND COUNT(DISTINCT PageID
    ) = 2 
    --this checks that the total found is only 2
```

This way, you are looking for how many different PageIDs from that list appear with each GridID, and then keeping those GridIDs that match the count you are looking for. Let me know if this works.

Comment: I tried it but that didn't make any difference in the results @the-ttg-guy

Comment: I have edited my answer with a significant change. See if that resolves it.

Comment: I have tried and still trying with some modifications on your answer but that does not return a single record but even more @the-ttg-guy